# Equation numbering problem in LAtex

Tags: equations, pdftex

I am writing my thesis on LaTex. I am having problem with equation numbering. In first two chapters, equation numbering is ok but in 3rd chapter equation numbering is like **3.0** and sometimes equation number is not written there. Please can someone sort it out?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: the numbering is the result of the commands that you put in the file, if you give no hint at all what the input is no one can guess why the equation has number 0 (which will not happen by default.) Add a small but complete document that has an equation with a number ending `.0` and someone will debug,